# How to print References using R Markdown with Tufte

Tags: r, r-markdown, tufte

In the documentation for R Tufte, it says references are printed at the end of the document if `link-citations` is not set to `yes` in the preamble. However, I am unable to get the references to print at the end of a document, even when using [the R Tufte template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/tufte/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates/tufte_html/skeleton/skeleton.Rmd), without any modifications (except to change `link-citations` from `yes` to `no`). The end of the document, where references should be, is just empty.

What am I missing?

[Here is a screenshot of what I get after knit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYKyd.png). As you can see, a bibliography is not printed at the end of the document (despite references being used within the document template).

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The template knits fine using `pandoc-citeproc 0.10.5.1`

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer Does yours print a bibliography at the end of the document? Mine also knits, I just don't get a bib.

Comment: Here is what I get: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-YD8CpGr4ulg/WYI9RBMeeEI/AAAAAAAAAWo/oCkYtpFxJ2UTNBIQu4IlEsA4CsuHNfdJQCHMYCw/s0/2017-08-02_16-59-48.png

Comment: I am using the developer version of tufte. Try `devtools::install_github('rstudio/tufte')`

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer, Confirmed: dev version fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a bug with the version of tufte that is on CRAN (0.2). The references section will print using the development build, installed using `devtools::install_github('rstudio/tufte')`.